# youtubeの共有に自分のアプリを表示するには？

Tags: android, iphone

youtube動画の共有から動画URLを取得して自作のアプリに渡そうと思っています。
共有画面に自作のアプリを表示させるにはどのような方法が考えられるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Androidアプリでしたら、AndroidManifest.xmlにintent-filterとして下記を設定すれば、youtubeのandroidアプリの各動画の「共有...」にアプリが表示されるようになります。

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

[参考](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178041/android-youtube-share-a-youtube-video-to-my-app)

Answer (score -1):

AndroidManifest.xmlは

```
    <activity>
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

受け取るActivity(例:MainActivity) onCreate内に記述

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)) {
      Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
      if (extras != null) {
      CharSequence ext = extras.getCharSequence(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if (ext != null) {
         EditText editText = (EditText)findbyid(R.id.***);//例
          editText.setText(ext);//例
          }
        }
    }
```

[参考サイト](https://techbooster.org/android/application/1388/)